# Detecting class instance undefined method name in javascript

Tags: javascript, eslint

I'm working in a new-to-me large javascript codebase that is a work-in-progress. As happens often in a large codebase, a variety of people have added code that has not been tested. I just spent way too much time debugging an issue that ended up being caused by a misspelled method name (essentially a missing method):

```
    stream.renegotiate() // this is what is should have been
    stream.renogotiate() // this is what it was
```

The project is bundled using webpack, without linting. So I thought I could just add eslint to the webpack config and it would tell me about the problems. It works for misspelled global methods, but is not checking class member name spelling.

Here is my `.eslintrc` file:

```
  {
    "plugins": [
        "eslint-plugin-import"
    ],
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:import/recommended",
        "plugin:import/typescript"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "no-undef": "error",
        "no-extra-semi": "off",
        "no-unused-vars": "off"
    },
    "env": {
      "browser": true,
      "es2022": true
    }
  }
```

The typescript option is in there because a few of the newer files in the project are typescript, but still there are 100+ legacy javascript files that have been recently worked on that have issues.

Is there a way to get eslint (or some other checker) to be able to detect and error-report the example above of `stream.renogotiate()` without doing a fullscale migration to typescript?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out the typescript compiler can be used for exactly what I described above. You can use it in vscode to check individual files by adding this to the top of a .js file:

```
// @ts-check
```

If you want to check a whole project, create a `jsconfig.json` file wherever the root of the javascript content is, then run the typescript compiler from the command-line with this:

```
npx tsc -p jsconfig.json
```

In my case, it did exactly what I was hoping it would do, highlighted a significant number of undefined symbols, including the one originally referenced, with this output:

```
error TS2339: Property 'renogotiate' does not exist on type 'MediaStream'.
```

This is a great first-step in porting a large javascript project to typescript. Thanks to the vscode docs for the guidance: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/working-with-javascript

FWIW, here is what I used for my `jsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "commonjs",
      "target": "es2020",
      "checkJs": true,
      "allowJs": true,
      "noEmit": true,
      "skipLibCheck": true
    },
    "exclude": ["node_modules"],
    "include": ["src/legacy/**/*"],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is loosely typed and it's possible to monkeypatch new methods onto existing classes and objects at runtime, so (as far as I know) there's no way to catch these sorts of issues at build time without something like typescript, even if you know the object's type.

Consider the example below. The `test` function throws on the first invocation but not on the second, despite being passed the same `stream` instance both times.

```js
class Stream {
  renegotiate () {
    console.log('renegotiate invoked');
  }
}

function test (stream) {
  try {
    stream.renOgotiate();
  }
  catch {
    console.log('error trying to invoke renOgotiate')
  }
}

const stream = new Stream();

test(stream); // throws

Stream.prototype.renOgotiate = () => console.log('renOgotiate invoked');

test(stream); // doesn't throw
```

Comment: I understand that nature of javascript. But it seems plausible that a static analysis tool could run in some strict "only accept properties that I have explicitly defined" mode.

Comment: Fair enough. You _can_ declare types in JSDoc comments without going full typescript, and eslint will flag undeclared method/property access as potential problems. (I now realize that this might've been a more helpful answer.)

Comment: This might be helpful: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html

Comment: Thank you - this link is probably the best answer, reading through it and the general topic its a part of seems like the best next step: get typescript to type-check my .js files using a jsconfig.json.